# Rails generating one project with xml and other with json formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Ruby on Rails projects on my computer. For some reason, when I generate a scaffold in one project I get:

```
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and in the other:

```
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The weird thing is that I am generating both in the *same* computer. 
When I do ruby -v I get 1.9.2.

How can I configure the scaffold to generate one or the other? Right now I am interested in .xml, but maybe I'll switch both to json someday. Anyways, I know I can do this manually, but it is a lot of work if you have several tables (or even with one table). How can I tell rails I want one format in particular by default?

Comment: Are they both using the same version of rails?

Comment: one that generates xml has rails 3.1.1 and the one that generates json is 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're using different version of rails in the two applications.. Rails 3.0 scaffold generates the xml code and Rails 3.1 scaffold generates the json code.. Check your gem list for multiple version of rails installed..

Comment: Actually, the one that generates xml has rails 3.1.1 *but in Gemfile appears as rails 3.0.10 for some reason) and the one that generates json is 3.1.0 (and in the gemfile it has 3.1.0 as well).

Comment: I updated the gemfile to 3.1.1 to have the same version of rails as the other one, but the scaffold is still generating json

Comment: I am pretty sure that rails >= 3.1 scaffold will generate json and not xml.. Maybe there's something wrong with the Gemfile.lock.. Check what version of rails does it specify..

Comment: you are right! The Gemfil.lock of the xml one says rails (3.0.10) and the one that generates json says 3.1.1, even though both of them say 3.1.1 when I do rails -v, should/can I change this manually?

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late.. The easy way to change this is to remove your Gemfile.lock and do a bundle install but before that specify in you Gemfile what version of rails you desire..